# Countability of specific sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I need some help with the following: 
are the following countable or uncountable?

1. the set of all lines in the plane with rational slope. - I think this is countable
2. Q{$0$} - I know Q is countable but does it need the zero to form a bijection?
3. N\ {1,3} - I know N is countable
4. {(x,y) $\in$ R x R | x+y = 1}
5. [0, $\infty$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that countable means finite or same cardinality as $\Bbb N$.

1. This lines do not have to pass through the origin, right?
2. Any subset of a countable set is countable.
3. See 2.

For 4. and 5. you need to know that $[0,1]$ is uncountable; recall that a set is uncountable if it has an uncountable subset.

4. Think of projecting this to $x$-axis.
5. $[0,1]\subset [0,\infty)$

Comment: For 1. It does not mention anything about the origin.. but how would this affect it if it did?